# How to reload tab page after changing tab name in Ionic to center text?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have code which changes the name of a tab in Ionic. This is done via an observable. It changes the tab name from "Account" to the username. I thought it'd be fun.

However, when ionic draws its tabs, if the original name is longer than the new name, then the result is a left justified username:

[image]
[image]

How do I make it redraw the tabs page so that it properly calculates how to center the text?

Comment: Just let css do it. `ion-tab { text-align: center }`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Then I tried angular 4 beta 15. Fixed it without the CSS

Comment: Cool, not sure what effect angular would have on it but glad you got a remedy. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, I mean Ionic 4 Beta 15.